# Arithmetic progression with common difference 2061

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

If there are 30 consequent members of an arithmetic progression with CD of 2061, show that among them are at most 20 squares of natural numbers.

I wrote out $a_1$ through $a_{30}$ and tried to find some patterns. Maybe it's checking modulos, then which ones? How is it done? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: There exists no arithmetic progression of squares of length 4. Some times you have to use this theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{30}$ be your arithmetic progression and suppose $a_k=y_k^2,\,\forall k.$
 Consider that equation
$$y_{k+2}^2-y_k^2=2\times 2061$$
$$(y_{k+2}-y_k)(y_{k+2}+y_k)=2\times 3^2\times 229.$$ 
If $y_{k+2}, y_k$ are integers, should be same parity. Otherwise $y_{k+2}^2-y_k^2$ become an odd integer.
If both are even $y_{k+2}^2-y_k^2$ is divisible by $4.$
If both are odd $y_{k+2}^2-y_k^2$ is divisible by $8.$
Hence $y_{k+2}^2-y_k^2=2\times 2061$ has no integer solutions.

Therefore, consider how that perfect squares can put in to your progression.

Her I give you a one possible progression containing $16$ perfect squares,
$$y_1^2, y_2^2 ,.., ..,y_5^2, y_6^2 ,.., ..,y_9^2, y_{10}^2,.., ..,y_{13}^2, \\y_{14}^2 ,.., ..,y_{17}^2,y_{18}^2,.., ..,y_{21}^2,y_{22}^2,.., ..,y_{25}^2,y_{26}^2,.., ..,y_{29}^2,y_{30}^2.$$

Consider all such possible progressions. Then you have the answer.

Comment: @Nilon I guess by pigeonhole principle there are at least 5 pairs of consecutive perfect squares and once again by pigeonhole principle because we have 3 integer solutions to x^2-y^2=2061, a contradiction, right?

Comment: I feel that you did not get my idea completely. so, I edited it. If you fee uncomfortable with this,please tell me.

Comment: This is really cool.

Comment: Now it's kind of obvious that your construction is maximal, but how do we prove it rigorously?

Comment: Oh and yeah isnt it 16 squares